# STM32F091 timer as a prescaler for another timer

Tags: stm32, timer, stm32f0, hal-library

I would like to chain two 16-Bit timers to each other to make a 32Bit timer. Just like the example in the datasheet [RM0091 figure 147 page 429] but with different timers.

I found these two sites:

- http://www.proiotware.com/index.php/9-blogs/9-stm32-chaining-two-16-bit-timers-to-create-32-bit-timer
- http://www.makaidong.com/%E5%8D%9A%E5%AE%A2%E5%9B%AD/20151013/307069.html

And I would like to get it working with the STM32F091TC.
There is a 32bit Timer onboard but it's being used by "mbed os". At the moment I'm trying to get it working with timer 16 and 15. With timer 16 being the prescaler for timer 15.

[RM0091 table 71 page 513] You should be able to use the internal trigger connection ITR2 = TIM16_OC to connect timer 16 as an input of timer 15.

Link to datasheets: https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f091rc.html

At the moment my code works as far as seeing Timer 16 running, but Timer 15 isn't increment from overflows of output compares of timer 15.

My code is the following:

```
#include "mbed.h"
DigitalOut led1(LED1);
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim15;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;

void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{

  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM15)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM15_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(htim_base->Instance==TIM16)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM16_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* TIM16 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM16_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM16_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_MspInit 1 */
  }

}
static void MX_TIM15_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_Init 0 */

  TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_Init 1 */
  htim15.Instance = TIM15;
  htim15.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim15.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim15.Init.Period = 0xff;
  htim15.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim15.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim15.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_EXTERNAL1;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR2;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  __HAL_TIM_ENABLE(&htim15);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_Init 2 */
    // TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
    // sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_ITR2;//TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_ETRMODE1;// TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_ETRMODE2; //TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_TI1
    // sClockSourceConfig.ClockPolarity = TIM_CLOCKPOLARITY_BOTHEDGE;//TIM_CLOCKPOLARITY_NONINVERTED;
    // sClockSourceConfig.ClockPrescaler = TIM_CLOCKPRESCALER_DIV1;
    // sClockSourceConfig.ClockFilter = 0x0; //0xF;

    // HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim16, &sClockSourceConfig);
  /* USER CODE END TIM15_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM16 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */
TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig; 
  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 0xFFFF;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV4;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0xFFFF/2;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim16, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim16, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */
     sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;

  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim16, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim16, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);


 __HAL_TIM_ENABLE(&htim16);
}

extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;  
void TIM16_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim16);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_IRQn 1 */
 led1 = !led1;
  /* USER CODE END TIM16_IRQn 1 */
}

int main(void)
{
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_TIM15_Init();

   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim15);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim16);

  while (1)
  {

    float count = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim16);
    float count2 = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim15);
    printf("teller: %f\t%f\t%f\r\n",count,count2, count+count2*0xFFFF); 
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions or know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using STM32CUBEMX to config it?

Comment: I tried that also, but it's my first time to using cubeMX so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. But the code to start the timer is missing in the cubemx output

Comment: Of course, CUBEMX only generates the configuration code. You have to start the timer yourself (can also stop if necessary) and it is quite straight forward.

Comment: I'm using Coocox IDE, so I have to configure everything myself

Comment: @user150963 Coocox IDE is dead, iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working, I did change timers tough.
Now TIM3 is a prescaler for TIM16:

Here is my code:

```
#include "mbed.h"
DigitalOut led1(LED1);

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim15;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM15_Init(void);
void Error_Handler(void);


void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM15 global interrupt.
  */
void TIM15_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim15);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_IRQn 1 */
}

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{

  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM3)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM3_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* TIM3 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM3_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(htim_base->Instance==TIM15)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM15_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* TIM15 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM15_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM15_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspInit 1 */
  }

}



int main(void)
{
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_TIM15_Init();

   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim15);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);

  while (1)
  {


    float count = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim3);
    float count2 = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim15);
    printf("teller: %f\t%f\t%f\r\n",count,count2, count+count2*0xFFFF); 
    }
}

static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 0xffff;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;//TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM15 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM15_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_Init 0 */

  TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_Init 1 */
  htim15.Instance = TIM15;
  htim15.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim15.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim15.Init.Period = 0xffff;
  htim15.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim15.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim15.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_EXTERNAL1;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR1;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM15_Init 2 */

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}
```